# Why does Preview's export to PDF only export one page?

Tags: pdf, preview

I open a PNG with Preview, then drag another one into the sidebar, and then choose Export to PDF. The resulting PDF has only one page.

I tried again, after selecting all pages -- same result.

How do I export a multipage PDF?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It saves one **file** to PDF. It doesn't concatenate first. For whatever reason that was decided, that's what it does.

The quick workaround is to go to Print, then save as PDF from there. This will save all pages opened in the same window.

Comment: This is why Preview's "several files in one window, with consecutive thumbnails" is a confusing UI. Probably easiest to create PDFs in the Finder using the Quick Action provided.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save just the first page as pdf
2. Open it and open the Thumbnails tab
3. Drag all the other pages in the Thumbnails tab
4. Save the document

It works for me on Mojave.